# Delete Double Quote From Last Line of a Text File

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a text file with the extension of .txt with a double quote for the record count at the end of that text file every time the file is generated from a 3rd party program.

Therefore is there any methods or codes that I can utilize to delete the double quote of record count in the last line of the text file? Please advise regarding this. Thank you.

I do research but all quotes are removed.

```
::====== script starts here ===============
@echo off > NEWFILE & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
:main
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (myfile) do (
set S=%%a
set S=!S:^|^"^|=^|^|!
set S=!S:^|^"^|=^|^|!
set L=!S:~-1!
if '!L!' equ '^"' set S=!S:~0,-1!
echo.!S!
) >> NEWFILE
goto :eof
::====== script ends here =================
```

Output from program

```
"1"|"abc"|"123"
"2"|"abcd"|"456"
"3"|"abce"|"789"
"3"
```

Output with last line changed

```
"1"|"abc"|"123"
"2"|"abcd"|"456"
"3"|"abce"|"789"
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is assign the line to a variable and only echo it when there is a previous line.  With this logic the last line will be assigned to the line variable but will not be output to the new file until the last echo statement.

```
@echo off > NEWFILE & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
:main
set "line="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (myfile) do (
    if defined line echo !line!
    set "line=%%a"
) >> NEWFILE
(echo %line:~1,-1%)>>NEWFILE
goto :eof
```